# FFMediaElement: How to stream from CamLink 4K?

Tags: c#, wpf, ffmpeg

I would like to use Unosquare's FFME library (v4.2.330) to show a live stream from a Cam Link 4K hdmi grabber.Using the following code, however, the media element remains black, even though the media has successfully been opened and no exceptions are raised.

```
    <ffme:MediaElement     x:Name="media" 
                           Background="Black"
                           MediaEnded="media_MediaEnded"
                           MediaOpened="media_MediaOpened"
                           MediaFailed="media_MediaFailed"
                           MediaInitializing="media_MediaInitializing"
                           LoadedBehavior="Play"
                           UnloadedBehavior="Manual"
                           />


    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.media.Open(new Uri("device://dshow/?video=Cam Link 4K"));
    }

    private void media_MediaInitializing(object sender, Unosquare.FFME.Common.MediaInitializingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Configuration.PrivateOptions["framerate"] = "50";
        e.Configuration.PrivateOptions["video_size"] = "1920x1080";
        e.Configuration.PrivateOptions["vcodec"] = "rawvideo"; //also tried mjpeg
        e.Configuration.PrivateOptions["pixel_format"] = "yuyv422"; //also tried yuv420p
    }
    
    private void media_MediaFailed(object sender, Unosquare.FFME.Common.MediaFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        log.Error(e.ErrorException);
    }
```

Using VLC player everything works fine, so I suppose it has something to do with parameters set during `MediaInitializing`. In order to get the correct parameters I ran `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Cam Link 4K"` which outputs

```
Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Cam Link 4K':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1920x1080, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc
```

By running `ffmpeg -f dshow -pix_fmt yuv420p -i video="Cam Link 4K" -framerate 50 -vcodec mjpeg test.mkv` I am able to record everthing into the file.

During startup I am setting `Unosquare.FFME.Library.FFmpegDirectory = @"C:\ffmpeg";`, where I put the prebuilt binaries and shared libraries for ffmpeg 4.2.1 (win64). Also I made sure my project is targeting x64. Since `MediaElement` works with regular mp4 files, I am not sure which parameters/settings I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience of "Unosquare's FFME library", but base on my understanding of ffmpeg, the right code should be

```
private void media_MediaInitializing(object sender, Unosquare.FFME.Common.MediaInitializingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Configuration.ForcedInputFormat = "rawvideo";
    e.Configuration.PrivateOptions["framerate"] = "50";
    e.Configuration.PrivateOptions["video_size"] = "1920x1080";
    e.Configuration.PrivateOptions["pixel_format"] = "yuyv422";
}
```

`ContainerConfiguration.ForcedInputFormat` should be the right one for specifying the input format as '-f' option.
`ContainerConfiguration.PrivateOptions` is for specifying demuxer options, and 'vcodec' is the option for specifying output video codec, which have nothing to do with demuxer.

Please check https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#rawvideo-1.